# AngularJS Async data not showing with promise

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json, asynchronous

When I open the app, I do not get any data from the controller, though `console.log($http...)` will give me arrays of my desired data. It seems like the following code in my controller is loaded before the `$http` call.

```
ActivityService.getAll().then(function(data){
    this.data = data
})
```

Here are my files:

_home.html

```
<h1>This is the Home page</h1>
<div>{{msg}}</div>
<div>{{data}}</div>
```

app.js

```
 (function() {
   function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

     $stateProvider
     .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'main/_home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl as main',
            resolve: {
                activitiesPromise: function(ActivityService){
                  return ActivityService.getAll();
                }
            }
        })

     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home')
 }

 angular
     .module('ProTrak', ['ui.router', 'templates'])
     .config(config);
 })();
```

MainCtrl.js

```
(function() {

function MainCtrl($scope, ActivityService) {
    this.msg = "hello wROLD"
    ActivityService.getAll().then(function(data){
        this.data = data
    })
}

angular
    .module('ProTrak')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['ActivityService', MainCtrl]);

 })();
```

ActivityService.js

```
(function() {

  function ActivityService($http) {

    ActivityService.getAll = function() {
      return $http({
        url: '/activities.json',
        method: 'GET'
      });
    }
    return ActivityService
  }

  angular
    .module('ProTrak')
    .factory('ActivityService', ['$http', ActivityService]);
  }
)();
```

On the Backend side, I think it is working because I can `console.log` the data. I get the correct `json` when visiting this URL `http://localhost:3000/activities.json`

```
[{"id":1,"title":"first","description":"hello world","created_at":"2017-03-05T22:43:08.356Z","updated_at":"2017-03-05T22:43:08.356Z","workouts":[]},{"id":2,"title":"first","description":"hello world","created_at":"2017-03-05T22:43:38.313Z","updated_at":"2017-03-05T22:43:38.313Z","workouts":[]}]
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'angular_rails_csrf'
gem 'angular-rails-templates'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'
# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

**Solution:**

Controller:

```
(function() {

function MainCtrl($scope, activitiesPromise) {
    $scope.msg = "hello wROLD"
    $scope.data = activitiesPromise.data
}

angular
    .module('ProTrak')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'activitiesPromise', MainCtrl]);

 })();
```

app.js

```
 (function() {
   function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

     $stateProvider
     .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'main/_home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            resolve: {
                activitiesPromise: ['ActivityService', function(ActivityService){
                    return ActivityService.getAll();
                }]
            }
        })

     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home')
 }

 angular
     .module('ProTrak', ['ui.router', 'templates'])
     .config(config);
 })();
```

ActivityService.js

```
(function() {

  function ActivityService($http) {

    ActivityService.getAll = function() {
      return $http({
        url: '/activities.json',
        method: 'GET'
      });
    }
    return ActivityService
  }

  angular
    .module('ProTrak')
    .factory('ActivityService', ['$http', ActivityService]);
  }
)();
```

Comment: 'ActivityService.getAll' is not visible

Comment: So the problem was solved by fixing the erroneous dependency injection?

Comment: yeah, it was having a problem with `$scope`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the wrong dependency injection you are doing at:

```
(function() {

function MainCtrl($scope, ActivityService) {  // <-- First param is $scope
    this.msg = "hello wROLD"
    ActivityService.getAll().then(function(data){
        this.data = data
    })
}

angular
    .module('ProTrak')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['ActivityService', MainCtrl]); // <-- First dependency injecttion is ActivityService

 })();
```

Either remove the `$scope` from the `MainCtrl` or add `$scope` as the first dependency injection.

Possible solution:

## 1:

```
(function() {

function MainCtrl(ActivityService) {  // <-- Removed $scope
    this.msg = "hello wROLD"
    ActivityService.getAll().then(function(data){
        this.data = data
    })
}

angular
    .module('ProTrak')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['ActivityService', MainCtrl]);

 })();
```

## 2:

```
(function() {

function MainCtrl($scope, ActivityService) {  // <-- First param is $scope
    this.msg = "hello wROLD"
    ActivityService.getAll().then(function(data){
        this.data = data
    })
}

angular
    .module('ProTrak')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'ActivityService', MainCtrl]); // <-- Added $scope as the first dependency injecttion.

 })();
```

And now regarding the data part, as you are already resolving the promise using the `$stateProvider`, you should change your `MainCtrl` function to something like(assuming you go with style#1):

```
(function() {

    function MainCtrl(activitiesPromise) {  // <-- Added activitiesPromise resolved data
        this.msg = "hello wROLD";
        this.data = activitiesPromise.data;
    }

    angular
        .module('ProTrak')
        .controller('MainCtrl', ['activitiesPromise', MainCtrl]);

 })();
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes part of the problem. I am expecting something back from `{{main.data}}` in my `home.html` file. Currently, I am not getting anything. I tried to `console.log($http({
        url: '/activities.json',
        method: 'GET'
      });)`, I do get a response from it which includes an array with my desired object.s

Comment: I see that you are using `$stateProvider` to resolve the `ActivityService.getAll()` data. So why are you event injecting `ActivityService` factory in your `MainCtrl`?

Comment: I've updated my answer which mentions how you should change your `MainCtrl` controller function.

Comment: This is interesting, because it didn't work when I have  `.controller('MainCtrl', ['ActivityService', MainCtrl]);`, but it worked with `.controller('MainCtrl', ['activitiesPromise', MainCtrl]);`.

Comment: @Leogoesger that is because what you have in resolve can get injected in controller directly. Also, my answer was one of the issues that you solved :)

Comment: It would have worked, if you would have done something like:`(function() {

function MainCtrl($scope, ActivityService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.msg = "hello wROLD"
    ActivityService.getAll().then(function(data){
        vm.data = data
    })
}
}());`

Comment: @tanmay thanks for the suggestion. I tried both your method, and the old method: `resolve: {
                activitiesPromise: function(ActivityService){
                  return ActivityService.getAll();
                }
            }`. They both worked! The error was mostly from `$scope`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your resolve in `app.js` has injection issues. Try to resolve like this..

```
activitiesPromise: ['ActivityService', function(ActivityService){
    return ActivityService.getAll();
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('ProTrak')
  .service('ActivityService', function ($http, ENV) {

    this.getAll = function ($username) {    
       return $http({
        url: '/activities.json',
        method: 'GET'
      });
    };

}
```

use this pattern this will work better and will get rid of the issue.